# Enthought Canopy (python) does not scroll to bottom of output automatically

Tags: python, python-idle, canopy

I have just started using Enthought Canopy (v1.4.9 64 bit for Windows) instead of IDLE.  I am a complete beginner and teaching myself python from various online courses.

When I run scripts in IDLE the output scrolls to the bottom of the IDLE screen, so if I am asking for raw_input multiple times the user can see what input is being asked for each time and just enter it without having to manually scroll down to the bottom of the output before entering their input.  However, in Canopy the output does not scroll all the way to the bottom of the 'Python' window.

Is there any command I can put in a script to tell if to automatically scroll to the bottom?

I've tried to search for how to do this online but could only find tutorials on setting up scroll bars.

Comment: I downloaded canopy to experiment with it and searched online hoping I would find an answer for you but sadly both resulted in nothing. I can however tell you that you probably don't want to scroll all the way to the bottom.. the actual output is like somewhere in the middle. The ipython pane in canopy is a little weird I must admit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble. Canopy's IPython *is* IPython's QtConsole; the same behavior appears in a plain (non-Canopy) QtConsole. We'll see if we can find a fix.

Meanwhile, a workaround is to run plain (non-QtConsole) IPython: from Canopy's Tools menu, open a Canopy Command Prompt, then type `ipython --pylab qt` (or just `ipython` if you don't want pylab behavior), and run your script from there.

Comment: Glad to hear it. FYI, Stack overflow protocol, for the reference of others, is to mark your question as answered. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work